# Separating UNIQUEIDENTFIER values from possible varchars in datamapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having hard time to differentiate between 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER' & 'varchar' in a data mapping script. Its a mismatch of data.

I tried this so far:

```
--my_field is a UNIQUEIDENTFIER

    SELECT distinct my_field, len(my_field), count(my_field) 
    FROM my_table_ 
    WHERE len(my_field) < 36 OR len(my_field) > 36 
    group by my_field

    SELECT my_field, len(my_field) 
    FROM my_table_ 
    WHERE my_field LIKE '%[!#%&+,./:;<=>@`{|}~"()*\\\_\^\?\[\]\'']%' {ESCAPE '\'}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: uniqueidentifier is not a varchar, it's a guid. I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: more background to the issue please? and desired results

Comment: A uniqueidentifier is a 128-bit binary data type. Don't confuse a *textual* representation of a data type with *what it actually is*. Of course, you almost always see a textual representation because *that's how we commonly display data for humans to consume*. A uniqueidentifier will never have a length different to 128 bits, and it will never "contain" any characters at all.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - the table has millions of rows, and a few varchar values(or at least they are not GUID, which should not be ther ) are in the table now. I'm having trouble to differentiate those bad apples. How they ended up there its a different discussion. Thanks!

Comment: So... `my_field` as a `varchar(36)` column that should contain string representations of `uniqueidentifier` but in some rows it contains values that can't be converted to `uniqueidentifier`, and you want to find these rows?

Comment: yep, you got it - @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your SQL Server version is 2012 or higher (and if not, you really should upgrade, since 2012 is the earliest version still supported by Microsoft) - you can use `try_cast` - it will return null if the cast fails:

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    my_field varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T (my_field) VALUES
('608DC3C3-1B2E-47AA-9362-33CD76DA3F6A'), ('A3871EA9-172D-49DD-8874-A850857F01FB'),
('A3871EA9-THIS-IS-WRONG-A850857F01FB'), ('And so is this')
```

Query:

```
SELECT my_field
FROM @T
WHERE TRY_CAST(my_Field AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) IS NULL
```

Result:

```
my_field
A3871EA9-THIS-IS-WRONG-A850857F01FB
And so is this
```

Comment: issue was just an ESCAPE SEQUENCE, replaced ' with '' fixed it.  FML!